# How to replace Wordpress default search with Woocommerce search

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help replacing the default Wordpress search with Woocommerce search.

Tried this in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts' );
function custom_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_search() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'product');
    }

    return $query;
}
```

but the output of the search is still just a list of post-like search results. I would like the same output (product archive'ish) as the Woocommerce search outputs.

Is that possible?

Comment: You have to create a page template for search.php in your theme/child theme. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Answer (score 0):

Found a plugin. If anyone else wants a solutions without coding: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-menu-extension/